# How can they add $SOS$ in inequality?

Tags: inequality

When reading on some webs, I saw some people can strengthen the inequality by adding $$\frac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{ab+bc+ca},\frac{ab+bc+ca}{a^2+b^2+c^2},\frac{8abc}{(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)},\frac{9abc}{a+b+c},...$$ with a number $k$. Like this example:

From this inequality:$$\sqrt{\frac{a}{b+c}}+\sqrt{\frac{b}{c+a}}+\sqrt{\frac{c}{a+b}}> \sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}(1)$$
They can make it stronger by adding $\frac{a+b+c}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}}$:
$$\sqrt{\frac{a}{b+c}}+\sqrt{\frac{b}{c+a}}+\sqrt{\frac{c}{a+b}}\geq \sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}\frac{a+b+c}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}}(2)$$

But I can't solve this, I just solved the first one.
Or this one:$$\frac{\sqrt{a^2+ab+b^2}}{(a+c)(c+b)}+\frac{\sqrt{b^2+bc+c^2}}{(b+a)(a+c)}+\frac{\sqrt{c^2+ca+a^2}}{(c+b)(b+a)}\ge \frac{3\sqrt{3}}{8a+8b+8c}\left(\frac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{ab+bc+ca}+5 \right)$$

I can't even solve this and don't know how they could find the $RHS$. Or this one too:$$\frac{a}{a^2+1}+\frac{b}{b^2+1}+\frac{c}{c^2+1} + \frac{(a-b)^2(b-c)^2(c-a)^2}{(a+b)^2(b+c)^2(c+a)^2} \leqslant \frac 32.$$

The:$$\frac{(a-b)^2(b-c)^2(c-a)^2}{(a+b)^2(b+c)^2(c+a)^2}$$ is a big problem for those inequalities!
Can anyone explain for me how they did this and introduct the name of this method please? Thank you a lots! I just want to know how they did this and the way for solving all of these when knew the original one, like I knew how to prove $(1)$ so how can I use it to prove $(2)$. That is a very big questions for the beginner like me, and also how can they find the fraction which they added in. Thank a lots!